# converting a nested dictionary to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert a nested dictionary to a df object.

the dictionary looks like this :

```
{'result': {'2011-12-01': {'A': 53, 'B': 28, 'C': 32, 'D': 0}, 
'2012-01-01': {'A': 51, 'B': 35, 'C': 49, 'D': 0},
 '2012-02-01': {'A': 63, 'B': 32, 'C': 56, 'D': 0}}}
```

and my goal is to have a table with the dates(second level keys) using as an index,
and the A,B,C,D as columns.

| date | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2011-12-01 | 53 | 28 | 32 | 0 |
| 2012-01-01 | 51 | 35 | 49 | 0 |

I tried to use a for loop to grab the inner keys/values and append() it to a DF, but all I've got was a long DF with a date index followed by a plain index.

My failed attempts:

```
print(sorted(columns[0].values()))
df = pd.DataFrame(index=result['result'].keys() , columns= columns[0].keys())
for i in range(len(columns)):
    a=sorted(columns[i].items())
    df=df.append(a)
print(df.to_string())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d['result']).T
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d['result'], orient='index')
```

Output:

```
             A   B   C  D
2011-12-01  53  28  32  0
2012-01-01  51  35  49  0
2012-02-01  63  32  56  0
```